# supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow not called in iOS 9 AppDelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios9

I'm testing our app with the iOS 9 GM and i'm not seeing supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow called at all in my AppDelegate.

I'm expecting this delegate function to be called when the app is rotated:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask) application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window
```

This worked fine in iOS 7/8.  Is anyone else seeing this or have any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: Any luck on this question ? If you have found any work around for this let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Same problem here with an ipad on iOS 9.1
The method is called on the simulator but is not called with a real device.
It all works fine with an iPhone 6+ (real or simulator)

Comment: I have Ipad with version ios 9.1 and in it supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow method called each and every time.

Answer (score 20):

You need to check the box "Requires full screen" in the General Targets setting - then it works here.

[image]

I guess the background is, that Apple wants us to provide all orientations, plus that these all work with iOS 9 split-screen, slide over etc.

See their documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/AdoptingMultitaskingOniPad/)

Look for "Characterize Your App and Scope Your Work":

> **Adopt Slide Over and Split View unless you have a specific reason not
>   to.** From a customer’s perspective, an iOS 9 app that doesn’t adopt
>   Slide Over and Split View feels out of place.
>
> Consider opting out only if your app falls into one of these narrow
>   categories:
>
> Camera-centric apps, where using the entire screen for preview and
>   capturing a moment quickly is your primary feature Full-device apps,
>   such as games that use iPad sensors as part of their core gameplay